# Is it a valid markup to put some tags inside <button> tag?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
<button class="btn_add_your_qora" type="submit">
    <div class="add_your_qora ">
        <a>send</a>
    </div>
</button>
```

Both the JS (`on click`) and the CSS (`hover` of that inner `div`) works well on Chrome. But neither JS nor CSS (`hover`) doesn't work on FireFox. Is it the markup valid? If yes, What's the problem?

Comment: You could [read the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/sec-forms.html#the-button-element) to find out what elements are allowed. *hint*: Content Model determines what child elements the element may contain.

Comment: `<a>` inside really doesn't make much sense though

Comment: Button can not have child elements (valid), so Chrome is just nice and 'repairs' it for you

Comment: That markup is silly IMO. Typically the only items I have within a button are text or some elements like an icon to aid in the buttons communication (still used as text). I would never put an element in a button then bind events to them - the buttons should be the event handling element.

Comment: @PoulBak not true. can have phrasing content

Comment: @PoulBak No a text node is not but this big list of [Phrasing Content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#phrasing-content-2) elements are. Please stop making uninformed comments. They just lead to more people being uninformed.

Comment: Anyway, a <div> inside a button is not valid!

Comment: That this is invalid HTML is reason enough to close the question.

Comment: @Radmation In fact, interactive elements, such as `<a>`, are specifically not allowed by the spec.

Comment: @Rob what if you use font awesome and place the <i class="fa fa-something"></i> I do this sometimes and it works across every device. I don't know why an inline element would be considered invalid markup. I guess you could always use the :after pseudo class and get it in there that way though too...but i find just placing the <i> quicker.. Is that invalid markup?

Comment: @Radmation The problem with what he did was putting an anchor within the button element. That is what made it invalid.

Answer (score 2):

That is not valid HTML. Buttons' context are [Phrasing Content](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/content-models.html#phrasing-content) so they should only contain text nodes, or content that marks up the text node. Also they can't have [interactive content](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/content-models.html#interactive-content) as descendants, so you can't have an `<a>` tag inside it, either.

Instead you should style your button with the style of the div and make the action of the button the same of the `<a>` tag, or better yet, just style `<a>` tag like the button + the div.

For more information about `<button>` check [this](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/the-button-element.html).